# Who receives the error email notifications of a failed Flow process?

Tags: flow

Salesforce sends out system emails notifying a developer/admin when a Flow process fails. How is the recipient of that email determined ? Is it always the creator of that Flow, or is there another determining factor ? Is that stipulated in another place ?

Email from failed Flow processes are being sent to an ex-developer of our company and I would like to have those emails sent elsewhere.

ftr : The flow is not set up to perform any kind of email action. I dont't think it would matter in this case, but I thought I would mention it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The flow creator is the one who always receives emails for unhandled faults. You'll want to open the flow and resave it using your credentials so the emails will come to you instead.

**Edit 08-03-2020**

While the above was correct at the time it was written in 2015, see @AnveshThakkallapally answer below which discusses the Summer 18 updates that allow an admin to change this behavior without needing to re-save a flow.

Comment: But if I only resave it won't it continue to go to the creator ? It sounds like I need to delete it and then re-create it myself....?

Comment: make a minor change (add a space, etc. then delete the space so you can save). It should save under your credentials since you'll be the last modified. If it doesn't, then copy and paste everything.

Comment: This is a ridiculous limitation.  Please upvote this idea to allow these email notifications to be configurable:  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DvMGAA0

Comment: @Scott Enough have voted up the idea that it's currently under Product Team Review. I'd say it has the team's attention but have added my vote as well. ;)

Comment: N.B. for others reaching this answer - for Visual flows, Flow Creator gets email, but for Process Builder, user that activated the process gets email. Consistency?  Not.

Comment: This is no longer the correct answer for this question (as of Summer '18).  The correct answer is now that by Anvesh Thakkallapally.  There is no longer any need to re-create the flows.

Answer (score 6):

**Good News with Summer'18 release**:
When a process or flow interview fails, Salesforce sends an email with details about everything that was executed and what failed. **Now we can decide on who should be receiving the flow error emails irrespective of who deployed/last modified the flow/processbuilder**

**Step1:** Go to setup>email administration>Apex exception email> add as many user you want (*you can also add external email addresses*) who needs to get the flow error emails from salesforce.

**Step2:** Go to setup> process automation settings> change the drop down value of **"Send Process or Flow Error Email to"** from "User who last modified the process or flow" to **Apex exception email recipients**

Comment: thanks @Anvesh, I think this is still the right answer at ending 2021.  -> step1 : https://YOURORG.lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/ApexExceptionEmail/home. -> step2 : https://YOURORG.lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/WorkflowSettings/home (at the bottom)

Answer (score 1):

If you have too many flows, I'd recomend you retrieve and re-deploy the flow defintions with the ant-migration tool.

1. Retrieve all the flows and create a copy of the flows.
2. Delete the activeVersionNumber tag. Leaving an almost "empty" file :

Original

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlowDefinition xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <activeVersionNumber>18</activeVersionNumber>
</FlowDefinition>
```

Modified

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlowDefinition xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
</FlowDefinition>
```

For this I recomend using Sublime with a regex search&replace of

`"<activeVersionNumber>.*</activeVersionNumber>"` --> `""`

3. Deploy these modified flow definitios to your production org. Luckily flowdefintions do not require nor autorun test.
4. Re-Deploy the original FlowDefinitions.

Voila, the user who re-deployed the FlowDefinitios will recieve teh emails.